Linear combination of unitaries with Qiskit circuit
I'm reading the PennyLane tutorial on linear combination of unitaries (LCU) algorithm.  Does Qiskit have any in-built functions that let me do the same thing?
Specifically, I want to build a circuit (two qubits) and apply a non-unitary matrix.  This matrix is decomposed into unitary matrices using PennyLane's LCU algorithm.  Does Qiskit have an equivalent LCU algorithm?  How do I convert the Pennylane/Qiskit LCU outputs into circuit operators?  Here is a MWE:
import numpy as np
import qiskit as qk
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
import pennylane as qml

c = 0.2  # constant between -1 and 1

# qiskit circuit
circuit = qk.QuantumCircuit(qk.QuantumRegister(2), qk.ClassicalRegister(1))
circuit.initialize(np.array([1,2])/np.linalg.norm(np.array([1,2])), [1])
circuit.initialize(1/np.sqrt(2)*np.array([1,1]), [0])

# matrix to be decomposed
A = np.array([[c,  1-c, 0,  0],
              [1-c, -c, 0,  0],
              [0,  0, -c,  1-c],
              [0,  0, 1-c, c]])
LCU = qml.pauli_decompose(A)
LCU_coeffs, LCU_ops = LCU.terms()

print(f"LCU decomposition:\n {LCU}")
print(f"Coefficients:\n {LCU_coeffs}")
print(f"Unitaries:\n {LCU_ops}")

# apply LCU results to qiqskit circuit
#circuit.unitary(Operator(A_LCU), [0, 1], label='A')

circuit.draw(output='mpl')


It is very convenient to use classiq for LCU https://docs.classiq.io/latest/classiq_101/quantum_primitives_with_classiq/linear_combination_of_unitaries/#guided-implementation  because of the optimization of the mcx - using synthesis preferences you can trade off between width and depth. It is also concinient thanks to the fact you do not need to dexompose the control variable to butstring, since the langauge is using qnum instead qbit

Great question. As far as I know, there is not an out-of-the-box function to do this in Qiskit; however, coding it isn't very difficult.
Below is the code for the same example in the Pennylane tutorial but only using qiskit functions.
# imports
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp, Operator


# Create non-unitary matrix
a = 0.25
b = 0.75

A = np.array([[a,  0, 0,  b],
              [0, -a, b,  0],
              [0,  b, a,  0],
              [b,  0, 0, -a]])


# Pauli Decomposition of A
LCU = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(A)
LCU_coeffs = LCU.coeffs
LCU_ops = LCU.paulis

L = len(LCU_coeffs)              # Total number of Paulis
M = int(2**np.ceil(np.log2(L)))  # Closest power of 2 to encode coefficients in statevector
pad = M - L                      # Value by which statevector needs to be padded


# lists of α coeffs and U unitaries for LCU
α_lst = np.pad(np.sqrt(LCU_coeffs)/np.linalg.norm(np.sqrt(LCU_coeffs)), pad_width=(0,pad))
U_lst = [op.to_instruction() for op in LCU_ops]


# Define ψ
ψ = np.array([1,0,0,0])


# Specify number of qubits
N = A.shape[0]         # Size of square-matrix A
n = int(np.log2(N))    # Number of qubits needed to encode A
m = int(np.log2(M))    # Number of qubits to control unitaries


# Create LCU registers
qr_ψ = QuantumRegister(n, name='ψ')
qr_c = QuantumRegister(m, name= 'ctrl')
cr_c = ClassicalRegister(m)


# Create LCU circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr_ψ, qr_c)
qc.prepare_state(ψ, qr_ψ)
qc.prepare_state(α_lst,qr_c)

for i in range(L):
    ctrl = np.binary_repr(i,m)
    U_ctrl = U_lst[i].control(m,ctrl_state=ctrl)
    qc.append(U_ctrl,qr_c[:]+qr_ψ[:])
    
qc.prepare_state(α_lst,qr_c).inverse()

This code returns the following circuit:

Since I am initializing $|\psi\rangle$ to be $|00\rangle$, the unitary of this circuit will still show the encoding of $A$ in the top-left block of the total unitary $U$ (I just left the initialization in the code in case you want to modify it to be something else).
So, looking at the total unitary:
U = Operator(qc)
print(U)

returns:
[[ 0.25  0.    0.    0.75 -0.43  0.    0.    0.43]
 [ 0.   -0.25  0.75  0.    0.    0.43  0.43  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.75  0.25  0.    0.    0.43 -0.43  0.  ]
 [ 0.75  0.    0.   -0.25  0.43  0.    0.    0.43]
 [-0.43  0.    0.    0.43  0.75  0.    0.    0.25]
 [ 0.    0.43  0.43  0.    0.   -0.75  0.25  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.43 -0.43  0.    0.    0.25  0.75  0.  ]
 [ 0.43  0.    0.    0.43  0.25  0.    0.   -0.75]]

Which has $A$ encoded in $U$, as expected.

Thank you for the detailed answer.  Is it possible to do LCU without a control qubit?  Ideally, I want to work with just 2 qubits and therefore a 4x4 matrix operator.

No. That's impossible. The way LCU works, is by applying the non-unitary operation probabilistically, which means you need an ancillary register (where the control qubits reside) so you can measure it and use the outcome to know if you projected the state onto the right subspace. Another way to think about it is that, you are "embedding" a non-unitary matrix into a larger matrix, so you obviously need a larger space (i.e., more qubits).
